# How to pass "x-www-form-urlencoded" POSTMAN parameter in Send HTTP Request activity in TIBCO?

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

I am trying to make a POST request using SendHTTPRequest activity in Tibco BW 6.5. In POSTMAN I am able to do so by passing "**x-www-form-urlencoded**" in body tab and able to get the response also.

How can I pass those parameters in SendHTTPRequest Activity of Tibco BW 6.5

Below is how I send the request in POSTMAN for reference

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for this. in the PostData field of SendHTTPRequest you can add the whole **x-www-form-urlencoded** parameters by taking it from the POSTMAN code snippet section. Another point to remember is in Header->Content-Type field of SendHTTPRequest you need to pass what type of input your are sending. In this case it will be **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"**

Cheers, 
Rudra

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a request with 'x-www-form-urlencoded', follow the instructions at the bottom:

1. Use SendHTTPRequest.
2. METHOD : POST
3. Accept: "application/json"
4. Content-Type:  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
5. mimeEnvelopeElement :
   content-disposition : 'form/data; name=$nameOfParameter'
   content-type : 'text/plain'
   textContent : $valueOfParameter
   ....

Look the image shared.
[image]